# How to enable Artifacts link

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I have a TFS2015 build definition: after the build step I have a PowerShell step which is publishing the build artifacts.

How can I enabled the Artifacts link in the build summary?

I've noticed that the Artifacts link is visible only when I have a Publish Artifacts build step in the build definition. I can't use this step because I need a specific folders structure in the build drop folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing might be to use your PowerShell script to prepare your drop as normal but then add the Publish Build Artifacts task so that the artifacts tab of the release is populated.

The example in this article uses $(build.stagingDirectory) to order the files and then specifies that directory in the Copy Root field of the Publish task.

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/

Comment: My vNext build can't seem to resolve $(build.stagingDirectory) path.  Is that a service-understood value? Or do I need to define it myself under 'Variables'?

I'm getting:


C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.targets(110,65): error MSB4184: The expression """.stagingDirectory" cannot be evaluated.

Comment: Solved my own issue: I had placed all the msbuild arguments into their own build-definition-level variable. Apparently , vNext didn't care for having to resolve a variable within a variable. Or there's something with the '$' symbol that needs to be escaped in that context?

Adding the msbuild arguments to each solution being built (9 of them) got us past that issue. It makes it tedious to make small adjustments, but at least it works now.